# How to remove packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services from build

Tags: yocto, bitbake

My image is pulling in `packagegroup-core-full-cmdline`, which is mostly fine as I want the features it provides.

However, that packagegroup in turn pulls in `packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services`.  This packagegroup is not necessary when using systemd as systemd can replace cron and at (systemd timers and services) and logrotate isn't needed by systemd-journald to do log rotation.

So I added this to my distro conf file to remove `packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services`:

```
RDEPENDS_packagegroup-core-full-cmdline_remove = "packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services"
```

This same processes worked to remove individual packages from other packagegroups.  But in this case is doesn't work.  I've verified that `RDEPENDS_packagegroup-core-full-cmdline` no longer includes `packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services`.  Yet I'm still getting `at`, `cronie`, `logrotate`, and `flex`.

If I couldn't remove `packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services`, then I can at least try to make that packagegroup empty.  So I added this:

```
RDEPENDS_packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services_remove = "at cronie logrotate"
```

And that has the desired effect: `at`, `cronie`, `logrotate`, and `flex` are now gone.  It also shows that this was the dependency that was bringing those packages in.

But why are the packages in `packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-sys-services` still getting included when nothing depends on that packagegroup?

The initial graph dependencies with all packagegroups unchanged.
(repeat dependencies between packages at different stages removed)

```
"linux-image.do_build" -> "cronie.do_build"
"packagegroup-core-full-cmdline.do_build" -> "cronie.do_package_write_deb"
```

After removing sys-services from the RDEPENDS of core-full-cmdline, the graph is *unchanged*.

After removing cronie from the RDEPENDS of sys-services, all references to cronie disappear from the build graph.

Comment: Can you try `RDEPENDS_packagegroup-core-full-cmdline_remove = "packagegroup-core-sys-services"`

Comment: I'm using Zeus, so that name isn't used anymore.  It's not in the final value of `RDEPENDS_packagegroup-core-full-cmdline`.  But I tried that too, since I wasn't sure how `namemap` worked, and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you check if there is another recipe that depends on packagegroup-core-sys-services? You can see all depends of your image by "bitbake -g {image-recipe-name}", it will create a graph file that you can view with a text editor if you don't want to get a dedicated program to open it.

Comment: I grepped the entire source for yocto layer tree for packagegroup-core-sys-services and didn't find any possibilities.  But I'll take a look at the graph again.  Though the graph doesn't seem to show entire path, with recipes shown as direct dependencies of the image recipe when in reality there are several indirect dependencies between them.

Comment: So `packagegroup-core-cmdline-sys-services` doesn't appear in the graph at all and never did (also without `cmdline`).  The packages in it, `cronie`, `logrotate`, etc. *do* appear in it.  They appear as dependencies of my image recipe and and of `packagegroup-core-full-cmdline`.  Removing sys-services from the rdepends of core-full-cmdline has no effect on that. Removing the packages from the repends on sys-services is necessary and sufficient to remote the packages.